# Format body mapping templates in API Gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Need your help! I have the below Lambda function that will take inputs from the API Gateway (using RestAPI Post method) and pass the same as Payload to a second Lambda function.

```
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
        customerName = event['Name']
        customerEmail = event['EmailAddress']
        
        input = {"Name": customerName, "EmailAddress": customerEmail}
        
        response = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName='arn_of_the_lambda_to_be_invoked',
        InvocationType='Event',
        Payload=json.dumps(input))
```

Below will be my input to the API Gateway in JSON format -

```
    {
        "Name": "TestUser",
        "EmailAddress": "test@abc.com"
    }
```

Have tried Lambda proxy integration and Generic Body Mapping templates (from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#input-examples-mapping-templates)). In both occasions, API Gateway returns the below error -

Response Body:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'Name'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 7, in lambda_handler\n    customerName = event['Name']\n"
  ]
}
```

With the same JSON input when I directly invoke the Lambda from the Lambda console, it works. I know that API Gateway, along with the JSON body, pushes many other things. However, I'm unable to figure out.

How do I get this working?

Comment: don't post image of text

Comment: The event mapping doesn't seem to have a key named 'Name'. Can you `print(event)` and check if the values are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the lambda proxy integration, the event will be in the following format.

```
{
    "resource": "Resource path",
    "path": "Path parameter",
    "httpMethod": "Incoming request's method name"
    "headers": {String containing incoming request headers}
    "multiValueHeaders": {List of strings containing incoming request headers}
    "queryStringParameters": {query string parameters }
    "multiValueQueryStringParameters": {List of query string parameters}
    "pathParameters":  {path parameters}
    "stageVariables": {Applicable stage variables}
    "requestContext": {Request context, including authorizer-returned key-value pairs}
    "body": "A JSON string of the request payload."
    "isBase64Encoded": "A boolean flag to indicate if the applicable request payload is Base64-encode"
}
```

the values you posted will be inside `body` as a json string. you need to parse the json.

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    fullBody = json.loads(event['body'])
    print('fullBody: ', fullBody)
    body = fullBody['body']
    customerName = body['Name']
    customerEmail = body['EmailAddress']
    
    input = {"Name": customerName, "EmailAddress": customerEmail}
    
    response = lambda_client.invoke(
    FunctionName='arn_of_the_lambda_to_be_invoked',
    InvocationType='Event',
    Payload=json.dumps(input))
```

[Input format of a Lambda function for proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format)

Please remember that the lambda is expected to return the output in the following format for Lambda Proxy integration.

```
{
    "isBase64Encoded": true|false,
    "statusCode": httpStatusCode,
    "headers": { "headerName": "headerValue", ... },
    "multiValueHeaders": { "headerName": ["headerValue", "headerValue2", ...], ... },
    "body": "..."
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ArunK. I have modified the Lambda as mentioned and now I'm passing the input as below -
`{
    "body": {"Name": "TestUser", "EmailAddress": "test@abc.com"}
}`
API Gateway returns 'Internal Server Error' and shows the below stack -
`Endpoint response body before transformations: {"errorMessage": "'dict' object has no attribute 'body'", "errorType": "AttributeError", "stackTrace": ["  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 7, in lambda_handler\n    body = json.loads(event.body)\n"]} Lambda execution failed with status 200: 'dict' object has no attribute 'body'`

Comment: Can you print the event

Comment: Sorry, how do I print the event? As I am using Lambda Proxy integration, the output has to be in a certain format right? Currently, below is my response handle in the Lambda function - `response = {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": "Lambda is in progress"
}`

Comment: I'm okay to even use body mapping templates and not use Lambda Proxy Integration. In that case, what would be my input handlers in the Lambda function?

Comment: add a `print(event)` before the customerName and check the lambda logs in cloudwatch

Comment: Yes, it does print the complete event.

Comment: Please share it here. please hide any sensitive data before posting it here.

Comment: Cannot share the complete output. It exceeds the no. of characters allowed in the comments. Any specific part of the output you're looking for?

Comment: I am interested in httpMethod, queryStringParameters, pathParameters, body. Again hide what you don't want to share :)

Comment: Here it is - `{'resource': '/', 'path': '/', 'httpMethod': 'POST', 'queryStringParameters': None, 'pathParameters': None, 'body': '{"body": {"Name": "TestUser","EmailAddress": "test@abc.com"}}', 'isBase64Encoded': False}`

Comment: ya got it. you have a `body` inside the body. updated my answer to cater that. good luck

Comment: Still failing with the same error - `Endpoint response body before transformations: {"errorMessage": "'dict' object has no attribute 'body'", "errorType": "AttributeError", "stackTrace": ["  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 8, in lambda_handler\n    body = json.loads(event.body)['body']\n"]}`

Comment: Re-iterating, I'm not inclined towards using Lambda proxy integration. I can do with body mapping templates as well. If I need to send `{"Name": "TestUser", "EmailAddress": "test@abc.com"}` as the request body, what should be my Lambda input variable and body mapping template?

Comment: Lambda proxy is not complicated. updated my code. can you show me the out of `fullBody`

Comment: Same error ---- `[ERROR] AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'body'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 8, in lambda_handler
    fullBody = json.loads(event.body)`---- My request body in API POST method is -- `{"body": {"Name": "TestUser", "EmailAddress": "test@abc.com"}}`--

Comment: my bad. can you do it again :) you have to do `event['body']` instead of  `event.body`. updated my answer again

Comment: One side question - Currently, I'm passing the POST Request Body as ---`{"body": {"Name": "TestUser", "EmailAddress": "test@abc.com"}}`--- Is there a way I can pass it just as ---`{"Name": "TestUser", "EmailAddress": "test@abc.com"}`---?

Comment: Yes . But you need the adjust the backend .

Comment: Yes, we can. How can we achieve it? Do we have to disable Lambda Proxy Integration and use Body Mapping templates?

Answer (score 0):

As best practice, you should **NOT** call a Lambda function from another Lambda function. Instead you should use [AWS Step Function (SFN)](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) to orchestrate your workflow. [Amazon Managed Airflow](https://aws.amazon.com/managed-workflows-for-apache-airflow/) is another solution.

SFN helps you with chaining Lambda output -> input, monitoring execution, debugging your chain of execution and visualizing the data flow through your workflow.

SFN can, not only call Lambda functions, but many other AWS Services APIs as well.